# In pentaho , Map component popup do not display the value after a refresh

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I used map markers with parameter, First the marker and popup works fine.
And when I change the parameter, markers refreshed ok but, popup with data shows nothing. 
I tried to solve, but nothing works. Kindly asking help

Comment: If anybody knows, kindly help us to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marker Click function test JS:

function f(){

**alert(this.dashboard.getParameterValue("status") +"   you have clicked on");**

//Dashboards.fireChange('status', e.vars.category.value);

}

Then you have to change the param values, check the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

In the marker click function you have to write the alert function first.